How to configure stackexchange.com so I see only hot questions from forums I've subscribed to?
I'd like to avoid seeing questions from forums other than those I have subscribed to when I log into stackexchange.com
The following screenshot shows what i see on login @ 13:25 6 Sept 2024:

There are questions that are currently hot on many topics from numerous forums, many of no great interest to me. I'd like to filter out those questions that belong to forums that I have subscribed to.
But I see no preference to achieve this.
Is there a way to include or exclude forums I want or don't want to see questions from ?

@Trunk there is also https://stackexchange.com/filters, is that what you are looking for?

What I want is the existing list of topical/interesting questions but with those from forums that I am not subscribed to excluded from the list. I tried the filters but found that it puts everything from every forum on its list.

@testing-for-ya  i did that. But it's not mixing the questions up enough, i.e. it's showing say 10-12 questions from SO, then 1 from Math O'flow, more from SO, an odd one from SE and so on.

But whatever the final as-displayed hot question list be, can't it thereafter simply be filtered by user criteria to remove unwanted ones ?

I'll have to think about this one as it's not just an issue for SE but for many informational sites, e.g. websites of newspapers, magazines, weather data, video sites, etc. It's desirable to do the filtration at the client end and spare the server enormous work expenditure. your solution of local stylesheets is interesting. Maybe a local DB too. For now, thanks.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
